# AWS amplify + cognito user pool : not able to get authenticated user after login without second call

Tags: vue.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I am using vue js and connecting to aws user pool via amplify, using
 `Auth.federatedSignIn();`
After user login from aws amplify hosted ui successfully, they will be redirected back to my home page (App.vue below).
I try to get the authenticated user when the page create, but it is throwing "not authenticated".

I try to call the function again (or refresh the page), and the user is able to be retrieved.

I also try to use setTimeout to add a delay, but seem vue doesn't update the page, which i am not able to see my currentUser on the screen.

What will be the best practice to getting the authenticated user right after the callback?

```
App.vue
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <v-btn @click="getAgain()">Get again</v-btn> #just a button to call again, and it able to get the user
    <h1 v-if="currentUser">user id : {{currentUser}}</h1>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
  export default {
    name: 'app',
    components: {
    },
    data() {
      return {
        currentUser: null
      }
    },
    created() {
      Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
        .then(user => {
          this.currentUser = user;
          console.log(user);
        })
        .catch(e => {});
    },
    methods: {
      getAgain() {
        Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
          .then(user => {
            this.currentUser = user;
          })
          .catch(e => {});
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: You might want to configure your amplify with congnitoId and other details before using it's methods.

Comment: What do you mean configure your amplify? I am able to login with cognito. The problem is I am not able to get the user immediately after the callback (in the created function). I need to click the "get again " button in order to retrieve the current login user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the sign in event and get retrieve the user once the event is triggered

```
  Hub.listen('auth', ({ payload: { event, data } }) => {
    if (event === 'signIn') {
      Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
        .then(user => {
          this.currentUser = user;
          console.log(user);
        })
        .catch(e => {console.log(e)});
    }
  });
```

Ref: https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/4621

Comment: Here If the user is already signedIn the app and the admin disabled the user. But the user still access the app. Hub.listen not returns any error message in its data. How can I know this disabled users state here?